# How to check my input field contains integer value in PHP?

Tags: php

This is not working ...if I insert any number it's showing error .. but why?

```
        if (is_integer($_POST['phn_number_1']) === false) {
                # code...
                $error[] = 'Please insert only integer! in "Phone number 1" Field ';
            }

            if (is_integer($_POST['phn_number_2']) === false) {
                # code...
                $error[] = 'Please only instert only integer in "phoner number 2" Field';
            }
```

Comment: What I think may be going on is that your form element's types are set to `"type="text"` - Do this `if(is_numeric($_POST['phn_number_1']))`

Comment: Is_numeric() working :D @TBI .. thanks ..

Comment: yeap .. it's like "<input type="text" name="phn_number_2">" .. @Fred-ii-

Comment: On a side note treating phone numbers as integers generally is a bad idea. In reality it's a string that may or may not consist of only digits.

Comment: `is_numerice` returns true for floats also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_integer` checks the variable type (all types from an HTTP post will be strings or arrays).

Instead, check out [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
if (filter_var($_POST['phn_number_1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    // not an integer!
}
```

Anything non-integer (floats, octals, etc) will return false.

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree. This is a better option than `is_numeric()` since that function will fail if a space is entered.

Comment: Excellent! .. this one is perfect! @webbiedave

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
if (!is_numeric($_POST['phn_number_1'])) {

    $error[] = 'Please insert only integer! in "Phone number 1" Field ';
}
```

Your method works too! But you have to be sure it's not a string! If your using is_numeric it also can be a string!

Comment: A number that `is_numeric` is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yep thats true! But it checks if it is numeric!

Comment: Worked! :D @Rizier123

Comment: There's a downfall to this, unfortunately. If a space is entered, it will not work, sorry to burst your bubble.

Comment: Tell me that's not your -1 in my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no it's not my -1! (An if i read it now it's a good answer so :D +1 from me :D)

Comment: Thanks, I had to ask. I did +1 yours from the beginning. I have no idea why that person would downvote my answer. Oh well, what can you do. And thanks for the +1

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's almost sad a down vote on a good answer like yours! I mean every answer from you under a php question is every time i read it top quality!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :) I made an edit in my answer to point out what the originally accepted answer was, being yours.

Answer (score 0):

The following is meant as a complimentary answer.

This will work for numbers only. No dots, spaces etc. just integers, **only** if you're 100% sure that the code only applies to `{...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...}`.

```
$var1 = $_POST['phn_number_1'];

if((string)(int)$var1 == $var1){ echo "All systems go."; } 

else{ echo "Sorry Charlie."; }
```

---

- Yet, `webbiedave`'s answer is also a good option, if not better.

Comment: Probably the down-voter thought your explanation was not accurate. Instead of `it's a number.` it should probably say yes its an `integer` and also `This will work for numbers only. No dots, spaces etc. just numbers.` should probably say this will work only for whole numbers. For example we can't say 12345.67 is not a number. Yes its not an integer but its a valid number: https://eval.in/218523

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I'd call that being pretty anal lol I'll change it just to satisfy their thirst ;)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Where I grew up, 0123456789 are called numbers. I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) *"An integer (from the Latin integer meaning "whole")[note 1] is a number that can be written without a fractional component. For example, 21, 4, 0, and −2048 are integers, while 9.75, 5½, and √2 are not."* but I like to think they're numbers.

Comment: All integers are numbers but all numbers are not integers. So numbers cant be aka integers

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky One of those cases of *"I want my cake and eat it too"*, but they won't let me till I'm good lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- To which [set](http://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html) does your solution apply to? Whole numbers are positive integers (0 included) meanwhile the natural numbers are positive integers (0 excluded). Integers are whole numbers along with it's complementary (i.e. negative numbers) meanwhile numbers are nothing but a set which contains all the other subsets. My point being, if it 's not suitable for, e.g. fractions or rational numbers, then *number* should be removed, otherwise it's okay. I'll up-vote (note that I haven't down-voted) once this has been settled :)

Comment: @Jonast92 Both webbiedave and mine give the same result. I don't need to keep going any further. I believe I have provided an alternate "solution", OP even said so: *" Thanks.. it's also working! @ Fred -ii- –  PHP Lover Nov 6 at 7:32"* - If that's your downvote, you don't need to retract it, I couldn't care less really. "I" know it works, the OP knows it works; what else needs to be said? It works.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Of course that's the most important factor, I'm simply asking about the _explanation_ which could be misunderstood since it's not compatible with the solution itself. I'm not here to argue, just pointing out a common mistake which has nothing to do with the solution, except that the solution is perhaps _wrong in association with your explanation_. I think you've overreacting and again, I did not down vote your answer, I'm just trying to *help* and make people up vote it by having a proper explanation.

Comment: @Jonast92 TBH, am at times unable to give an explanation, the most likely reason why the person downvoted. I wasn't saying it was you, I said "if" it was you. It happens at times where I'm unable to explain why code works, and like to provide an OP with a solution by testing a piece of code I either written and/or borrowed from code I found somewhere else, and testing it with actual values. If it passes the test, I then post it as an answer. If I do recally, I think I spent close to an hour trying to find the OP a solution. Sometimes going the "extra mile" bites me in the "you know what".

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand. I recommend that you simply change `This will work for numbers only, a.k.a. integers No dots, spaces etc. just numbers/integers` to `This will work for numbers only; no dots, spaces, etc.` to avoid any conflict of misunderstanding. Replace `numbers` with `integers` **only** if you're 100% sure that the code **only** applies to {...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...}.

Comment: @Jonast92 Thanks for the recommendation, I've edited it. Let me know if I've made an error, *cheers*.